# Convolutional Map output dimension

Tags: conv-neural-network

In this paper [***Let there be Color!***](http://hi.cs.waseda.ac.jp/~iizuka/projects/colorization/data/colorization_sig2016.pdf) implementing CNN, the properties are as follow:

- Image size: `224x224`
- Kernel size: `3X3`
- Stride: `2X2`
- Padding: `1x1`

In the paper, they mention that `the output layer size is 112X112` but calculating it using the formula `Num of outputs = ((Size-F+2*P)/S)+1)` [***[1]***](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convolutional-layer), the `result = 112.5`

Shouldn't the output be integer?

Comment: I think they mention in the paper that instead of performing max pooling they perform convolutions with stride 2. That means that the normal convolution operations are performed with padding `1 x 1` and stride 1. But after the convolutional layers instead of max pooling, they perform another convolution with stride 2 to reduce the spatial dimension.

Comment: I don't think so because in the paper the first conv layer performs convolution with stride 2 so the convolution layer involve max pooling form beginning not after traditional covolutional layer. - @Kashyap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I communicated with the paper author and he said

> it is implementation-wise, fractional sizes get rounded down so the
>   output would be 112x112

which means the last column will be neglected.

Comment: This is something that is new :| Then you are just throwing away the last column?? I suggest you rescale the image into appropriate scale. May be change the image size to 223. That would give you a whole number to work with